# How to align buttons in android layout to make a tabbar in a mobile website?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've investigated numerous sites about aligning buttons in android,however,I wasn't able to find a good tutorial. I tried to 
make 4 buttons align in the layout in android to make a nav bar like the image below. I know that tabs exists in android,however, I don't want to use those. I want to use layouts to make the nav bar like the image below. Are there any good options or samples? I made a mobile web app's nav bar with an ease, however, things arn't easy with android for me. I would want stack pro's helping hand!

[image]

I've attemped to make the nav bar but it seems not working quite well...

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#2cb22c"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#2cb22c"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rr"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/review2"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/r2"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/review"
                android:background="@drawable/ranking"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/s2"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="31dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ranking"
                android:background="@drawable/search"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/l2"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/search"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/fav"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please check the `id` in line `android:layout_toRightOf=""` for last 3 buttons. They do not match to any `id` in your layout.

Comment: remove the relative layout, make the width of the buttons 0 and add the following -> android:layout_weight="0.25"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick.

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#2cb22c"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#2cb22c"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/r2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="@drawable/r2"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/r2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="@drawable/r2"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="31dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="@drawable/s"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/l2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/s2"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="@drawable/f2"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#2cb22c"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rr"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:text="Home"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/s2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff5533"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:text="latest info"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#555555"
        android:text="Contact us"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```